# How to wait for the first arrived result on the thenable chain?

Tags: task, elm, elm-architecture

We can use [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to wait for the first arrived result on the `thenable` chain. The [Task](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Task) module doesn't seem to support it yet, [Task.sequence](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Task#sequence) is only the equivalent to [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Non-thenable **Solution** demo:

```
import Process
import Task


init () =
    ( Nothing, Cmd.batch [ after 2 "2nd", after 1 "1st" ] )


after seconds name =
    Process.sleep (1000 * seconds)
        |> Task.map (always name)
        |> Task.perform Done


type Msg
    = Done String


update (Done name) model =
    case model of
        Nothing ->
            ( Debug.log name <| Just name, Cmd.none )

        _ ->
            ( Debug.log name model, Cmd.none )


main =  
    Platform.worker
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = always Sub.none
        }
```

Run it, output as expected:

```
1st: Just "1st"
2nd: Just "1st"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.race` as a self-contained function requires maintaining local state to track whether or not it's been resolved already, which as you probably know isn't possible in Elm.

But you can accomplish the same thing relatively easily by tracking the state in the model yourself. Here's an example using `Maybe` to track whether we've received a response:

```elm
type Thing =
    ...

getThings : String -> Task Never (List Thing)
getThings url =
    ...


type alias Model =
    { things : Maybe (List Thing) }

type Msg
    = GotThings (List Thing)


init =
    ( { things = Nothing }
    , Cmd.batch 
          [ Task.perform GotThings (getThings "https://a-server.com/things")
          , Task.perform GotThings (getThings "https://a-different-server.com/things")
          ]
    )


update msg model =
    case msg of
        GotThings things ->
            case model.things of
                Nothing ->
                    ( { things = Just things }, Cmd.none )

                Just _ ->
                    -- if we have already received the things, ignore any subsequent requests
                    ( model, Cmd.none )


view model =
    ...
```

Comment: The user app can describe its intent for any side effect, whose execution is deferred to elm runtime. So I think that the function like Proimse.race can but yet be implemented by the runtime.